# How to prevent a field being updated without changing hibernate-mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a field in a hibernate mapping file...

```
    <property name="dateAdded" column="date_added" type="java.util.Date"></property>
```

and I would like to prevent that field being updated when I receive updates from upstream. Ordinarily, and ideally, I would tell hibernate not to update the field

```
    <property name="dateAdded" column="date_added" type="java.util.Date" update="false"></property>
```

but the mapping is part of a base jar and I'm haven't persuaded the owners to make this change, yet.

Is there a clean alternative way to achieve the same effect?

I'm trying to avoid copying the mapping file into my project, changing it and using the changed file, or writing any significant amount of code to look for the record in the database and apply the existing dateAdded value to the update record.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to write an Interceptor (best way is to extend EmptyInterceptor) and override the onFlushDirty method:

```
@Override
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id,Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState,String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
{
    boolean modified=false;
    if (entity instanceof YourEntity)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<propertyNames.length;i++)
        {
            String prop=propertyNames[i];
            if (prop.equals("dateAdded"))
            {
                if (!currentState[i].equals(previousState[i]))
                {
                    currentState[i]=previousState[i];
                    modified=true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```

You can add the interceptor with

```
org.hibernate.SessionFactory.withOptions().interceptor(yourInterceptor);
```

which return a SessionBuilder by which you can get your hibernate session.

I don't know if this is the best approach, but it should be working.